# \DoubleSpacing not working as described

Tags: memoir

Page 48 of the `memoir` manual states this about using `\DoubleSpacing`:

> The spacing in footnotes and floats (e.g., captions) is un- altered,
>   which is usually required once the controllers see what a blanket
>   double spacing brings.

The problem is that this is not working for me. When I compile several memoir style documents, there is no difference between `\DoubleSpacing` and `\DoubleSpacing*`. I would like to use double spacing as described in the manual (No double spaces in footnotes and floats). Any help?

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal document illustrating the problem?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that you have received some good answers to some of your other questions but you haven't accepted any of them (accepting answers is different from up-voting them); please, revisit your other questions and, if you consider so, accept the answer that best solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: I have the same question: how can I get `memoir` to leave footnotes single-spaced with the un-starred `\DoubleSpacing` command? I went through a whole series of tests to determine which package might be causing trouble, and I finally identified it: `arabxetex`, which I use to typeset Unicode Arabic text. I call the package with the line `\usepackage[novoc,fdf2alif,utf]{arabxetex}`, but the same problem exists when the package is called without options. If there is a solution, I would greatly appreciate learning about it. Would you consider reopening this question, @GonzaloMedina?

Comment: I have decided to post a [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197551/double-spacing-in-text-but-not-footnotes-in-memoir-class-while-using-arabxetex) separately, with an example file to illustrate the issue.

Comment: An [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197551/double-spacing-in-text-but-not-footnotes-in-memoir-class-while-using-arabxetex/200961#200961) to my similar question has been posted by Vafa Khalighi. It is possible that it would answer the question posed here.