# footnote double spacing with memoir package

Tags: footnotes, memoir, line-spacing

I haven't found any possible way to double space my footnote while using the `memoir` package. There is another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74912/doublespacing-not-working-as-described) which has been closed because not general.. well, I have the same request.

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Test a\footnote{\lipsum[1]} and b\footnote{\lipsum[1]}.
\end{document}
```

The only working command I found is `\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default version of the `\DoubleSpacing` command in `memoir` sets regular text double spaced but footnotes and captions etc., as single spaced.  However, there is a starred version of the command that will make *everything* double spaced.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\DoubleSpacing*

\begin{document}
\kant[1] This is some text\footnote{\kant[2]} Some more text.
\end{document}
```

If for some reason you only want footnotes to be double spaced, but captions still single spaced, you can modify the formatting of the footnote text independently.

Page 236 of the `memoir` manual shows the parameters that control the footnote formatting.  The macro `\foottextfont` can be redefined to make double spaced footnotes:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\DoubleSpacing
\renewcommand\foottextfont{\footnotesize\DoubleSpacing}

\begin{document}
\kant[1] This is some text\footnote{\kant[2]} Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote]

Comment: Which I suggest to use in combination with `\setlength{\footnotesep}{\onelineskip}`

Comment: I cannot use `\DoubleSpacing*` because I am already using the `\begin{Spacing}{2}` command in order to do not space excessively the bibliography.

Comment: @Atcold Use a `Spacing` environment only around the bibliography.

Comment: Oh, lol.. I haven't thought about it. Great tip.