# Double-spacing in text but not footnotes in memoir class while using arabxetex

Tags: memoir, line-spacing, arabic, bidi

The `memoir` class's `\DoubleSpacing` command without an asterisk (*) is supposed to double-space the text but not the footnotes or float text. However, when the `arabxetex` package has been loaded, this functionality is disrupted, such that in addition to the main text, the footnotes are also double-spaced (floats are still single-spaced as expected).

I am not the first to point out that sometimes `\DoubleSpacing` erroneously produces double-spacing in the footnotes; someone [already did](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74912/doublespacing-not-working-as-described#comment457183_74912) a year ago -- but that question was closed without being answered. I hope that now that I have identified the specific package (or at least one of the packages) which causes this problem, the question will be easier to answer.

The following example file, compiled with `xelatex` (MacTex 2014), produces double-spaced footnotes; I would like it to produce *single*-spaced footnotes (while keeping the package `arabxetex`).

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[novoc,fdf2alif,utf]{arabxetex}

\DoubleSpacing

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.\footnote{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}

\end{document}
```

### Update (2014-09-05)

As was pointed out in the comments below, the real problem is a conflict between the `bidi` package and `memoir`'s `\DoubleSpacing` command; once `bidi` is removed, the command functions as described in the `memoir` documentation (text double-spaced, footnotes single-spaced).

Just to be clear, I am not requesting a comprehensive fix of this problem, which I imagine would involve a modification of the `bidi` package itself. My question is simply whether there is a decent work-around which would allow me to achieve the desired result. (So far I have met with no success fiddling with `\baselineskip` and the other parameters described in `memman.pdf` §3.3.2 = pp. 48–49.)

Comment: Without looking at the code. My guess is that arabxetex messes with footnotes and thus overrides the memoir definition. In that case there is nothing memoir can do.

Comment: Perhaps one of the author/maintainers of `arabxetex` would know where to look? @Vafa Karen-Pahlav (who seems to be a user here on the TeX Stack Exchange) and François Charette are listed on CTAN; does anyone know how I might get in contact with one of them to inquire about this issue?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide an example that only depends on font available i, say, TeX Live. I cannot compile your example.

Comment: Looking at `arabxetex` it is clear that it does not mess with footnotes. But something in `bidi` does. Removing `fontspec`, `\setromanfont` and replacing `arabxetex` with `bidi` shows the problem. The footnotes are double spaced. `bidi` redefined lots of things in various classes, so small details like this easily gets lost.

Comment: Thank you, @daleif! I see what you mean. Perhaps the author of `bidi` (listed as @VafaKhalighi) would know how to fix this?

Comment: I have posted a `bidi` [bug report](https://github.com/vafa/bidi/issues/1) on this issue about this issue, in hopes that the package author will know where to look!

Comment: Oddly, the bug report link I posted in my previous comment is broken now. Does anyone know where I should post this `bidi` bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `\usepackage{arabxetex}`, put

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{extrafootnotefeatures}{bidi}
```

Comment: An example would be much more useful!

Comment: I have tried Vafa Khalighi's suggestion on the MWE which I provided in the original question and found that it resulted in precisely the output I had been seeking. I have accordingly marked this as the answer. Many thanks to @daleif for pinpointing the problem and to Vafa Khalighi for the solution!

Comment: I prefer no extra space between footnotes, so I have also added the line `\setlength{\footnotesep}{9pt}` (using the `12pt` option for `memoir` as in my MWE).