# Setting text in OnehalfSpacing, footnotes SingleSpacing with memoir

Tags: memoir, line-spacing, bidi

I'm using the memoir class, which is great, to set a dissertation. Unfortunately I have to use double spacing (for which I'm actually using OnehalfSpacing). When I do this, the whole document gets set in OnehalfSpacing. I'd like to set the footnotes in single spacing. Any idea how I can do that?

I'm using the bidi package and I have already tried the suggested fix in [Double-spacing in text but not footnotes in memoir class while using arabxetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197551/double-spacing-in-text-but-not-footnotes-in-memoir-class-while-using-arabxetex) but to no avail.

Here is an example, which shows that footnotes that are simply citations (\autocite{}) are correctly in as single spaced, but a \footnote{} ends up 1 1/2 spaced.

[image: Problem example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Single spacing is the default with `memoir` for footnotes, so please edit your question to show a minimal document which shows the problem (you can probably base it off off the one in the linked question.)

Comment: Apologies, I've now seen what the convention is - will do in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `bidi` with the `extrafootnotefeatures` option. Though, even then I needed to modify the memoir settings a bit to get things looking right.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{bidi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\OnehalfSpacing
\footmarkstyle{\hskip\footparindent #1.\@\space}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0in}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0in}
\begin{document}
\null
\vfill
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\footnote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\footnote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}
\end{document}
```

[image]