# memoir + XeLaTeX + DoubleSpacing still makes table floats double spaced

Tags: floats, xetex, memoir, line-spacing

When compiling a memoir document in XeLaTeX with the \DoubleSpacing command, floats are still double-spaced (but footnotes are not, as desired). (\DoubleSpacing should double space everything but floats and footnotes, while \DoubleSpacing* double-spaces everything, per memman.pdf) Once this exact same document is compiled in pdfLaTeX (with XeLaTeX-specific commands removed), the spacing is as desired (floats and footnotes single spaced, everything else double. MWE below:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{memoir}

% Comment out the following 3 lines and compile in standard LaTeX, and the table spacing is fine (single). Compile in XeLaTeX with the following three lines, and the table is double spaced. 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\DoubleSpacing
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Summary of results}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Cell & Cell  & Cell  & Cell \\ 
Cell & Cell  & Cell  & Cell \\ 
Cell & Cell  & Cell  & Cell \\ 
Cell & Cell  & Cell  & Cell \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I get this document to compile in XeLaTeX with \DoubleSpacing, but table floats single spaced?

Similar question here, but unanswered: [\DoubleSpacing not working as described](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74912/doublespacing-not-working-as-described)

Also here, but accepted solution does not work (and arabtex is not loaded in my MWE): [Double-spacing in text but not footnotes in memoir class while using arabxetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197551/double-spacing-in-text-but-not-footnotes-in-memoir-class-while-using-arabxetex)

Update: Thanks to the comment below, the problem was indeed an older version of memoir/texlive. The code compiles as expected with the latest versions of everything.

Comment: I do get the desired spacing with xelatex.  Is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: On another computer that had a fresh texlive 2016 installation, you are correct, it typeset as desired. When upgrading the texlive installation on the original computer, and updating all packages, it still typesets incorrectly (with double spaced tables). It does seem to be an issue with the versions but I'm not sure what's left to update to get it right.

Comment: If you've updated to TL 2016, you need to make sure that you  don't a have a  copy of `memoir` installed in your local `texmf` folder.  To check this, you can look in the log file: there the exact paths of each package loaded (and the class) will appear. Alternatively, from a terminal you can type `kpsewhich memoir.cls` which in TL 2016 should return `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either, but what about trying: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\SingleSpacing}`. If that works, you could wrap it in a conditional using the package `ifxetex`.

Comment: See if `\setFloatSpacing` helps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was an older version of memoir/TeXlive.

Comment: @lockstep I'm not sure it's even reproducible: I went back through my TeX Live archive (to TL'09) and didn't see an issue (earliest version `memoir.cls    2009/09/21 v1.61803398b`). So I'd say OT 'not reproducible' rather than 'needs an update' (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/questions-which-are-bug-reports-revisited/7008 for a position suggesting the latter should be answered not closed).